# how to replace double quotes with empty space in mysql?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, checkbox, mysql-workbench, kendo-treeview

Here `Question_ids_delete` is a string like " `'1','2','3'` ",
I want to remove double quotes in the input string, need output as '1','2','3'

```
DELIMITER $$
```

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `delete_QandA`(userid INT, subjectId tinyint, chapterId tinyint,  Question_ids_save text,  Question_ids_delete text)
BEGIN
 DECLARE statement_ids_delete text DEFAULT '';

set statement_ids_delete =TRIM(REPLACE(Question_ids_delete, '"', '' ));
IF (LENGTH(Question_ids_delete )>0) THEN

DELETE from products.my_class_room_subject_chapter_qanda
where classroom_chapter_usr_id = userid 
   && classroom_subject_id = subjectId && classroom_chapter_id = chapterId && classroom_chapter_question_id in (statement_ids_delete) ;

END IF;

END

Comment: I am testing in mysql editor by using call, as::: call products.delete_QandA(17, 1, 3, "11,123","'2','3'"); but no affect in the table

Answer (score 0):

Double the double quotes.

```
Question_ids_delete.Replace("""","");
```

Alternatively

```
String sourcestring = "" '1','2','3' "";
String matchpattern = @"""";
String replacementpattern = @"";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(sourcestring,matchpattern,replacementpattern));
```

Comment: i want to remove double quotes.. If i give Input as  " '1','2','3' ", then i need output as '1','2','3'

Comment: Yes, this will replace

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
REPLACE( field_with_double_quotes, '"', '' )
```

This will cause removing all double quotes.
And to remove leading and trailing spaces, use `TRIM()`.

```
TRIM(REPLACE(  " '1','2','3' ", '"', '' ))
```

will return a string `'1','2','3'` with no leading and trailing spaces.

***Refer to***:

1. [MySQL: Replace Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)
2. [MySQL: Trim Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

Comment: Hi, I am Using a procedure as shown below, actually its not working with above code. may i know the reason and solution?                                     Procedure: set statement_ids_delete =TRIM(REPLACE(Question_ids_delete, '"', '' )); DELETE from products.my_class_room_subject_chapter_qanda
where classroom_chapter_usr_id = userid 
   && classroom_subject_id = subjectId && classroom_chapter_id = chapterId && classroom_chapter_question_id in (TRIM(REPLACE(Question_ids_delete, '"', '' )) ) ;